# How do I make a simple interest calculator

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a challenge to practice. I'm trying to use an input to decide how much you would pay on a loan. Really basic stuff - but when I print I'm getting whatever was answered in the input repeating over and over again and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. The code I'm trying to run is:

```
# $200 a month at 1.7% interest a year. Automate total based on months using user input.

months_given = input("How many months? ")

monthly_base = 200
yearly_tax = (1.7 / 100 / 12)
monthly_tax = (200 * yearly_tax)
monthly_total = int(monthly_tax + 200)
total = int(months_given * monthly_total)


print(f"You will need to pay: ${round(total, 2)}")
```

I've tried using for/while loops but I'm not proficient with those yet and am still trying to understand how they work exactly.

Comment: Try with `months_given = int(input("How many months? "))`, i.e., convert the input into `int`. In your code, `months_given` is `str`, so `months_given * 2` for example equals `months_given` repeated twice.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I added `+ (monthly_tax * months_given)` to the end of my total line and that added the percent. Probably more steps than needed but stoked it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse your `input` first then use it.
when you use `input` it return `str`.

in this `total = int(months_given * monthly_total)` line. `months_given` is `str` and when you use `*` operator and second operand is an `int`, `str` value repeated.

correct:

```py
months_given = input("How many months? ")
months_given = int(months_given) # <-- here
monthly_base = 200
yearly_tax = (1.7 / 100 / 12)
monthly_tax = (200 * yearly_tax)
monthly_total = int(monthly_tax + 200)
total = int(months_given * monthly_total)


print(f"You will need to pay: ${round(total, 2)}")
```